# Laravel 6 not returning 404 when calling a not existing route

Tags: php, laravel

I have some issues with Laravel. I called `php artisan route:cache` and then the issues began. For example, the Auth routes (login etc.) can be called even if the User is logged in. Then the caching command seems to not clearing the routes. I noticed it because I put my Auth routes in the middleware `guests` because of the rendering of the Auth routes. After I ran `route: clear` it worked.

Also, the 404 routing doesn't work since that, because if I call a route that doesn't exist, then the Symfony Framework throws an error:

```
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException
```

That's my web.php:

```php
Route::get("/installer","install\InstallController@index");

Route::group(["middleware"=>"guest"],function(){
    Auth::routes();
    Route::post("login","Auth\Logincontroller@authenticate");
});

Route::group(["middleware" => "auth"], function () {
    Route::get("/logout","Auth\LoginController@logOut");
    Route::get('/', "dashboard\DashboardController@index");
});
```

Also, the `installer` route doesn't work. I will always get redirected to `localhost/dashboard` (even if I change the route name). My domain for the Laravel is called `raptor.debug`, so I don't know why it's redirecting to `localhost`.

Can someone point out what I did wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: Is that the full content of your `web.php` file? Also, have you tried `php artisan route:clear`?

Comment: FWIW, its definitely not a bug with Laravel, its almost certainly something missconfigured in your app. Do you have all the right values in your `config/app.php` file  for `name`, `url`, ...etc?

Comment: In the command line, you can also do `php artisan route:list` which will list all the configured routes and their details. This can be invaluable when working with problematic routes

Comment: @WesleySmith Yes that's my full `web.php`. I ran `route:clear` and the 404 was working again. But after I called `route:cache` the problems began again. Is there a problem with caching?

Comment: Try running `php artisan route:list` after you cache the routes and compare to before caching, see if that gives you any insight.

Comment: @WesleySmith I compared them and I only noticed that the unnamed routes got after caching `generate::'somestring'` as name. Besides that nothing is different.

Comment: Have you tried using `Install` and `Dashboard` for namespaces and folder names instead of 'install` and 'dashboard`

Comment: @AnasBakro yes that was the Problem thx!

Answer (score 1):

As Anas Bakro pointed out, the command `php artisan route:cache` will brick the app, when the **folder** of the **controllers** are **lowercased**.